# Activity Monitor showing my CPU usage is more than 100% ???(iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, cpu-usage, activity-monitor

My messenger Application is using more than 100% CPU usage.How can one program use more CPU than I have? What is that percentage based on?[image: ScreenShot of Activity monitor showing more CPU Usage]

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed as off-topic

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's per CPU core. A two-core CPU can go to 200%, 4-core to 400%, etc.